# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php

I'm trying to put html code into the variable, can't understand what i'm doing wrong here.

with the following code i'm getting

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end
```

the code

```
if (!empty($VIDEO_META)){
        $og_video = <<<HTML
                <meta property="og:type" content="video" />

                <meta property="og:video" content="{$CURRENT_URL}"/>
                <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="{$CURRENT_URL}"/>

                <meta name="og:video:height" content="280" />
                <meta name="og:video:width" content="420" />
                <meta name="og:video:type"  content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
        HTML;
}else{
        $og_video = <<<HTML
                <meta property="og:type"  content="website" />
        HTML;
}
```

Comment: Try putting the heredoc against the left-side of the document and remove any whitespace after <<<HTML please.

Comment: It's the heredoc. Has to be at column 0 (first character in code line) in your script

Comment: Besides, don't know if others have problems with heredocs - but I run into problems using heredoc always - that's why I don't use them. And, there are more readable ways anyway, than using them.

Comment: You're welcome. And I second djot. Use HereDOC sparsely or refer to an alternative since it's quite prone to causing errors. Also, would you be so kind as to accept my answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HereDOC `( $og_video = <<<HTML )` is wrong, it has to be a the direct start of a line.
Check: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php for details on this.
Also remove any whitespace after HTML, that causes errors too.

Otherwise, there's really nothing wrong with it, should work quite nicely.